# How to save all user clicks and inputs in Django?

Tags: django

This is may be an obvious question to a Django expert, but is there a way that I can save all user input (clicks and text-based). If this is possible, then how do I access it later?

Or must I create models for each entry and then save each click by hand in the view with something like to save user behavior, obviously it would be way bigger than this, in the application:

```
#(within a view function)
UserInputs.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user,
        selection1=request.POST.get('selection1'), 
        id=request.POST.get('id')),
        thumbs_up=request.POST.get('thumbs_up'),
        thumbs_down=request.POST.get('thumbs_down'),
        comments=request.POST.get('comments')
 )
```

Comment: if you have model UserInputs and in view you have object of that you can save your object in view

Comment: When you say user clicks and views are you expecting to keep log of user's url visit? If yes then a small custom middleware can solve your question.